# TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/ Invalid block tag on line 23: 'translate', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django-templates

**
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
Invalid block tag on line 23: 'translate', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Invalid block tag on line 23: 'translate', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: C:\Users\subramanyam.s.g\PycharmProject\pyyshop\LEARN\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 522, in invalid_block_tag
Python Executable:  C:\Users\subramanyam.s.g\PycharmProject\pyyshop\LEARN\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3**

Answer (score 2):

I also happened to come across this error while using Django Version: 2.1.

I was customizing the admin look and feel as per the django documentation 3.1 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial07/.

Django Version: 2.1 can be hosted in a shared hosting domain with reference to https://pythonfusion.com/deploy-django-on-shared-hosting/.

Here is part of the screenshot to just show you i got the same error and see where the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV52y.png

If you have difficulty finding where the Django source files(the ones you want to customise eg admin) are located on your system, use the following procedure:

1. In your computer locate where your django project is located in the file explorer e.g
   C:\Users\yourname\Desktop\yourproject.
2. In your file explorer window, there is a path above your folder showing your current
   location in the file explorer e.g This PC > Desktop > yourproject. Click inside this
   path and rewrite cmd and then hit enter key on your keyboard. A command prompt will be
   opened.
3. Now if you installed django in a global environment, that is, in local disk without
   creating a virtual environment enter this code `python -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"` in the opened command prompt.
4. If you installed Django into the virtual environment then activate first the virtual environment using still the opened Command prompt, i normally use `workon myvirtualenvironmentname` to activate my virtual environment. Then paste this code `python -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"` in the opened command prompt.
5. Hit enter key on your keyboard and you will see something like this `['C:\\Users\\yourname\\Envs\\yourvirtualenvironmentname\\lib\\site-packages\\django']`. This is the location we should arrive to access the Django resources.
6. Go to your file explorer by pressing `CTRL + E` on your keyboard.
7. Navigate to your `local disk C`, open the `Users` folder, next open the `folder with your name` next locate and open the `Envs` folder and locate your `yourvirtualenvironmentname` your project is using.
8. Open your `yourvirtualenvironmentname`> `Lib` > site-packages > django > contrib > admin > templates >admin.
9. You should be here `C:\Users\yourname\Envs\yourvirtualenvironmentname\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin` in your machine.

Now take key note on the Django version you are using. Where we are currently `there are some files that are in Django Version: 2.1 and not in Django Version: 3.1` e.g app_list.html is in Django Version 2.1 and not in 3.1 with respect to this directory where we are.

Note 2. **The file names maybe the same but the content inside the file may differ slightly and this is what causes the error**

The code below is some of the content in base.html (i have just copied a few of the code where i want to emphasize ) from Django V 3.1.

**base.html from Django Version 3.1**

`

```
{% if not is_popup %}
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="branding">
    {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% block usertools %}
    {% if has_permission %}
    <div id="user-tools">
        {% block welcome-msg %}
            {% translate 'Welcome,' %}
            <strong>{% firstof user.get_short_name user.get_username %}</strong>.
        {% endblock %}
        {% block userlinks %}
            {% if site_url %}
                <a href="{{ site_url }}">{% translate 'View site' %}</a> /
            {% endif %}
            {% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %}
                {% url 'django-admindocs-docroot' as docsroot %}
                {% if docsroot %}
                    <a href="{{ docsroot }}">{% translate 'Documentation' %}</a> /
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if user.has_usable_password %}
            <a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% translate 'Change password' %}</a> /
            {% endif %}
            <a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">{% translate 'Log out' %}</a>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
</div>
<!-- END Header -->
{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% translate 'Home' %}</a>
{% if title %} &rsaquo; {{ title }}{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}

<div class="main shifted" id="main">
  {% if not is_popup and is_nav_sidebar_enabled %}
    {% block nav-sidebar %}
      {% include "admin/nav_sidebar.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
  {% endif %}
  <div class="content">
    {% block messages %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}
          <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
        {% endfor %}</ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endblock messages %}
    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="content" class="{% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}">
      {% block pretitle %}{% endblock %}
      {% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
      {% block content %}
        {% block object-tools %}{% endblock %}
        {{ content }}
      {% endblock %}
      {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
      <br class="clear">
    </div>
    <!-- END Content -->
    {% block footer %}<div id="footer"></div>{% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>
```

`

I wanted to highlight these lines of code but i was unable. So check of the following in your base.html  `{% translate 'Welcome,' %}`, `{% translate 'View site' %}`, `{% translate 'Documentation' %}`, `{% translate 'Change password' %}`, `{% translate 'Log out' %}` and `{% translate 'Home' %}`.

Lets compare the above base.html file with that of Django Version 2.1. Take a close look to discover the difference.

**base.html file in Django Version 3.1**
`

```
{% if not is_popup %}
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="branding">
    {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% block usertools %}
    {% if has_permission %}
    <div id="user-tools">
        {% block welcome-msg %}
            {% trans 'Welcome,' %}
            <strong>{% firstof user.get_short_name user.get_username %}</strong>.
        {% endblock %}
        {% block userlinks %}
            {% if site_url %}
                <a href="{{ site_url }}">{% trans 'View site' %}</a> /
            {% endif %}
            {% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %}
                {% url 'django-admindocs-docroot' as docsroot %}
                {% if docsroot %}
                    <a href="{{ docsroot }}">{% trans 'Documentation' %}</a> /
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if user.has_usable_password %}
            <a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a> /
            {% endif %}
            <a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">{% trans 'Log out' %}</a>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
</div>
<!-- END Header -->
{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
{% if title %} &rsaquo; {{ title }}{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}

{% block messages %}
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}
      <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock messages %}

<!-- Content -->
<div id="content" class="{% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}">
    {% block pretitle %}{% endblock %}
    {% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% block object-tools %}{% endblock %}
    {{ content }}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
    <br class="clear">
</div>
<!-- END Content -->

{% block footer %}<div id="footer"></div>{% endblock %}
```

`

You will see the following in your base.html  `{% trans 'Welcome,' %}`, `{% trans 'View site' %}`, `{% trans 'Documentation' %}`, `{% trans 'Change password' %}`, `{% trans 'Log out' %}` and `{% trans 'Home' %}`.

To solve your ***TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/ Invalid block tag on line 23: 'translate', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?**
*

Just rename the translate to trans and save your file. In conclusion whenever you will add app_list.html or any other file in your admin folder and get and error. Just open the file and rename anything that has translate to trans. This solved my problem.

Incase i miss quoted something for example the django versions remember to let me know. Lets learn together. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can come up with for this could happen is if you've created a custom tag module named 'i18n' which would override the builtin i18n module. I can reproduce it by creating a file 'i18n.py' in my app's templatetags/ folder - is that what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a template I've copied and modified. The template was from newer version of django. After upgrading django it all normalised.